# If I install a firmware file My debain os geting very slow

Tags: debian, firmware, realtek, slowdown

I installed this [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek)  frimware file in my debian os for my wifi driver.

If I uninstall this [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek) . then my pc works very fast.

If I install [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek) again my pc works very slowly.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'firmware-realtek' instead of './firmware-    realtek_20190114-2~deb9u1_all.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firmware-realtek
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/506 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,602 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/simba/Downloads/firmware-realtek_20190114-2~deb9u1_all.deb firmware-realtek all 20190114-2~deb9u1 [506 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package firmware-realtek.
(Reading database ... 136550 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-realtek_20190114-2~deb9u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-realtek (20190114-2~deb9u1) ...
Setting up firmware-realtek (20190114-2~deb9u1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_33.0.4.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It looks like you are using Debian 9. Does the same happen with Debian 10 or Debian 11?

Comment: @A.B I am using debian 11.

Comment: Explain: What exactly is slow and how do you measure it? Are there any unusual messages in syslog or journal?

Comment: @U.Windl If I install `firmware-realtek`  my pc works very slowly. before , install `firmware-realtek` my pc works very fastly eg: if I open a browser it will open with in a sec. but , after I install `firmware-realtek` if I open a browser it 1 min to open.

Comment: A friend of mine asked me about this same problem a few days ago, so I don't think it is related to your specific machine. Which realtek device do you have? Post the output of lspci.

Comment: lspci : https://github.com/PradeepSimba/AndroidUSBCamera/raw/master/README.md

Comment: Your firmware link is from Debian 9. You might be running Debian 11, but you installed a Debian 9 firmware. Here's Debian 11's firmware: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-realtek (package version 20210315-3 versus yours version 20190114-2~deb9u1) . At the very least you're supposed to check if up-to-date soft... firmware fixes the issue. Nothing tells it will, but that's what to try first. Also you shouldn't have to do this manually. It should be used from the correct repository settings for Debian 11 non-free (it appears you are using the wrong).

Comment: Actually you edited the first line of your apt-get command to make it look like it wasn't downloaded manually, which can hinder help.

Comment: I installed this package https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-realtek But, this not worked

Comment: Digging around in the logs (journalctl -xe) I found some references to AER which led me to another forum post that had a workaround. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1588428, which is talked about on https://askubuntu.com/a/771908 as well.

Workaround is to disable AER and/or MSI by adding a kernel param to your boot cmdline, either `pci=noaer` or `pci=nomsi`. I personally have tried this and seen it work on at least one machine.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter to learn more about adding kernel params.

Comment: Please , Can you explain in detail ? Because I am new to linux.

Comment: The arguments you would add are as described there, `pci=noaer` or `pci=nomsi`, you might have to try both to see what works. The last link is an article describing where you will add this argument and how to do it. It happens as the computer is booting up.